# How to create a very simple jquery slideshow from image array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slideshow, caption

I have an image array that comes from php and converted to JavaScript array. 
The codes.

```
    var imgs = ["data/lst/seasonal/lst-2002-Apr-May-Jun.png",
            "data/lst/seasonal/lst-2002-Jul-Aug-Sep.png",
            "data/lst/seasonal/lst-2002-Oct-Nov-Dec.png"]
    var cnt = imgs.length;

    $(function() {
        setInterval(Slider, 5000);
    });

    function Slider() {
    $("#imageSlide").show("fast", function() {
       $(this).attr("src", imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).show();
    });
    }
    <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" />
```

The code works but lacks few important things.

See the [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zwtcwsgh/) http://jsfiddle.net/zwtcwsgh/

I would like have the following features.

```
  1. Using image file names all caps minus extension as a caption. 
     eg. LST-2002-OCT-NOV-DEC
  2. With back and next buttons. 
  3. stop animation on mouse hover. 
  4. animation without a break. Something similar to show(); 
  5. loading animation till the entire images are loaded.
```

The most important once are 1, 2,3

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you considered any 3rd party libraries for slideshow e.g. http://bxslider.com/

Comment: I have considered them but they are to big for php echo output.

Comment: Why you want to echo that script rather than just <script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, bxslider.js can be linked in the page. In my case when users make a search for images in a range, php gets the array of images within a range. Then the output should come with a slideshow based on the user request.

Answer (score 1):

Print them out to an , then you can use [Unslider](http://unslider.com/). I think you might need to work a bit on the captions, but this is a great little extension I use a lot

Comment: Could you tell me how to add dynamic image array in it?

Comment: I tried it but it only displays them without the slide show. I have linked unislider.min.js with script src. Then I added this.

Comment: echo  'var cnt = imgs.length;'; 
 
    echo '
 
for(i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
    $("#slider_list").append("<li><img src="'; echo '+imgs[i]+'; echo '"></li>");
}
$(function() {
    $("banner").unslider();
});
       ';
  echo '</script>';  But it only displays the images without slideshow.

Comment: You should have: Jquery js, Unslider js, Unslider CSS

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get the unslider css on the unislider website and gitub page.

Comment: .banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
    .banner li { list-style: none; }
        .banner ul li { float: left; }

Comment: I have added that from the beginning.